# how to solve this error : 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to code a counter app in which pressing the "Button" increments the counter and displays it in the TextView. I followed the exact same procedure as my online teacher. But, the code is not running.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall_grad"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:text="The counter app"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_heading" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_counter"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.198" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
package com.example.counter_08_01_23;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView heading1 , counter_text1;
    Button btn1;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        heading1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_heading);
        counter_text1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_counter);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button_counter);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Adding functionality

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter_text1.setText(inc_counter());
            }
        });
    }

    public int inc_counter(){
        return ++counter;
    }

}
```

The Log is as follows :

> 

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.counter_08_01_23, PID: 22639
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.counter_08_01_23/com.example.counter_08_01_23.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3197)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
at com.example.counter_08_01_23.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7376)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7367)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3177)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22639 SIG: 9

Comment: ditch your online teacher, findViewById was obsolete way to get reference view in android, use viewBinding it would never throw NPE, there is tons of tutorial of how to use viewbinding out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise views below set content

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


heading1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_heading);
counter_text1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_counter);
 btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button_counter);
```

You can use view binding which make your work more easier

Answer (score 0):

##### - Here, you need to change just the line up and down. Because you declare `findViewById()` first of inflating XML Layout.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Raise your layout to Java class level.

    // Then find Your view from xml
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button_counter);
    ...
}
```